# JavaScript - Call function and navigate to the location inside a HTML anchor

Tags: javascript, html

I have a anchor tab inside my HTML code:

```
<li><a href="default.aspx" id="go" onclick="myFunction()">Navigate</a></li>
```

and Javascript as follows:

```
function myFunction()
        {
            var user121 = document.getElementById('lblUser').textContent

            var parameters = {
                u: "?u=" + user121
            }
            var $query = parameters;
            output.firstChild.nodeValue = $query;
            alert($query);
            window.location ="Default.aspx"+$query <!-- Not sure about this part-->
        };
```

Basically what I need to do is when I click on the `<a>` attribute I want to build a query-string and navigate to the page.

1. If the href is not in the code the Javascript does not get fired.
2. If the href is there then the page next loads but the query string is not build.

Basically the question is can I have a javascript function in a `<a>` that build a query string and navigate to the next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **href="#"** or **href="javascript:;"**

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="go" onclick="myFunction()">Navigate</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `myFunction`, you can `return false;` so that the default behavior of a clicked anchor tag is not triggered.

```
function myFunction()
    {
        var user121 = document.getElementById('lblUser').textContent

        var parameters = {
            u: "?u=" + user121
        }
        var $query = parameters;
        output.firstChild.nodeValue = $query;
        alert($query);
        window.location ="Default.aspx"+$query <!-- Not sure about this part-->
        return false;
    };
```